# Counting Combinations

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, sorting, combinations

I have an Oracle table with multiple columns some populated with a variable, there a large number of possible variables the example below is not exhaustive.

```
ID  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 Col6
-------------------------------------
1   X2    B2
2   C3    D1    R4
3   B2    X2
4   E4    T1    W2
5   X2    B2
6   R4    D1   
7   D1    R4    C3
```

I need to identify the number of distinct combinations where row 1, row 3 and row 5 in the above example are considered the same combination and rows 2 and 7 are also considered the same.  So the desired result would look like:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Count(*)
------------------------------------------------
B2    X2                            3
C3    D1    R4                      2
E4    T1    W2                      1
D1    R4                            1
```

But if I use this:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Count(*)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC
```

Then row 3 in my data is considered unique.  However, it has the same combination as rows 1 and row 5.  Also row 2 and 7 are not considered the same and the result is:

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Count(*)
------------------------------------------------
X2    B2                            2
C3    D1    R4                      1
B2    X2                            1
E4    T1    W2                      1
R4    D1                            1
D1    R4    C3                      1
```

It looks like I need to sort the col variables before comparing them. But is there an elegant solution to doing this for large record sets (3 million+ records) with up to 20 columns of data in Oracle?

Comment: combination of col1 and col2 only right? but what is with R4 AND W2?

Comment: no, I need to consider all columns, I will add some more rows to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that come to my mind. First you can write a function accepting six or more strings and concatenating them in order. Then:

```
select colstring, count(*)
from
(
  select id, concat_sorted(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) as colstring
  from MyTable
)
group by colstring;
```

Another way would be to make each column a separate record and use listagg on them, provided you have Oracle 11g or higher available:

```
select colstring, count(*)
from
(
  select id, listagg (colx, ',') within group (order by colx) as colstring
  from
  (
    select id, col1 as colx from MyTable
    union all
    select id, col2 from MyTable
    union all
    select id, col3 from MyTable
    union all
    select id, col4 from MyTable
    union all
    select id, col5 from MyTable
    union all
    select id, col6 from MyTable
  )
  group by id
)
group by colstring
```

Comment: Thanks Thorseten, I have just tried your second method, but I get the error message:ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.

Comment: When I try the first method I get the following error:  ORA-00904: "CONCAT_SORTED": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: Hi, that's strange with that maximum string size. There are just six values per id. So maximum needed length should be length(col1) + length(col2) + ... + length(col6). Are your real-world values in col1 to col6 very long? Otherwise I assume a bad implementation of listagg on Oracle's side. I don't have that function available here, as we are still on Ora 10g. We use a custom string aggregation routine and that works well. Sorry, I cannot help here.

Comment: As to CONCAT_SORTED being unknown to Oracle: Of course it is. This is the function that needs to be written by yourself. This is what I was talking about here: "write a function accepting six or more strings and concatenating them in order".

Comment: The real world has about 20 variables of up to 3 characters per row.  Sorry I missed the advice to write the concat_sorted function.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
WITH t AS (
SELECT 1 ID, 'X2' col1, 'B2' col2, NULL col3, NULL col4, NULL col5, NULL col6 FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2, 'C3', 'D1', 'R4', NULL, NULL, NULL  FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 3, 'B2', 'X2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 4, 'E4', 'T1', 'W2', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 5, 'X2', 'B2', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 6, 'R4', 'T1', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 7, 'D1', 'R4', 'C3', NULL, NULL, NULL FROM dual
)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, tot_count
FROM (
     SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, cnt,
            MAX(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY val) AS tot_count,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rn
     FROM (
          SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, val, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY val) cnt
          FROM (
               SELECT A.ID, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, val
               FROM (SELECT ID, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6
                    FROM  t
                    ) A,
                    (SELECT ID, listagg( val,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY  val DESC) AS val 
                     FROM (
                         SELECT ID, val
                         FROM   t
                         unpivot ( val FOR origin IN (col1,  col2, col3, col4, col5, col6))
                         )
                     GROUP BY ID
                     )b
                WHERE A.ID = b.ID
                )
           ORDER BY val
           )t1 
     )t2
WHERE tot_count = cnt 
AND rn = 1
ORDER BY tot_count DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks Dba, but I have a large number of possible values in the columns, I have only shown a few rows as an example.